# .ajax() refreshes the page after ENTER is hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to update the db with a new folder but it refreshes the page after ENTER is hit.
on my form I have `onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) savefolder();"` 
here is the javascript code that I have: what it does basically is after you hit enter it calls the function savefolder, savefolder then sends a request through ajax to add the folder to the db. Issue is it refreshes the page... I want it to stay on the same page.
any suggestions? Thank you

```
<script>


 function savefolder() {

var foldername= jQuery('#foldername').val(),
    foldercolor= jQuery('#foldercolor').val();
//  ajax request to add the folder
            jQuery.ajax({   
                type: 'get',
                url: 'addfolder.php',
                data: 'foldername=' + foldername + '&foldercolor=' + foldercolor,       
                beforeSend: function() { alert('beforesend');}, 
                success: function() {alert('success');}
            });

return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have `e` declared twice (in the `doc.ready()` and as `window.event`), and `return false;` at the end of `savefolder()` should (I imagine) cancel the form submit, if that's how it's attached. What you've posted doesn't strictly make sense (where is the end of the `doc.ready()` block?).

Comment: Also, *ajax* doesn't run a roundtrip; the fact your `submit` handler doesn't cancel the `submit` event is what does. I've not seen an approach like you've got (maybe it's IE-specific?), and I don't see where you declare the `submit` handler.

Comment: @JaredFarrish he has an `inline onkeypress` event defined on the form tag...

Comment: @Xander - Ahh, I see. Is there any particular reason for this type of approach vs. a submit handler? (Really, I'm wondering...)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Usually inline event binding in HTML is shunned as you're tightly coupling `HTML` to `JS`. Though, there's nothing stopping you. Yeah, usually the standard method is attaching to the submit event of the form - at least that what I usually do...

Comment: @Xander - I don't see/know of a reason why trapping the `enter` key `keypress` is of any use (especially in an inline event handler) to simply using `onsubmit` (inline or not), which is triggered by an `enter`. Unless there's some other detail (like clicking a `submit` button needs alternative behavior).

Comment: @JaredFarrish agreed - seems like all he really needs to do is add `onsubmit="function() { return false; }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7899/discussion-between-xander-and-jared-farrish)

Comment: there is no submit savefolder will pass parameters to addfolder.php that will update the db, in return success: will display a div that says: folder added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="search">
</form>

function savefolder() {
    var foldername= jQuery('#foldername').val(),
        foldercolor= jQuery('#foldercolor').val();

    jQuery.ajax({   
        type: 'get',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        //data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + koo,       
        beforeSend: function() {
            //fe('#r'+koo).slideToggle("slow");
        },
        success: function() {
            $('form').append('<p>Append after success.</p>');
        }
    });

    return false;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(savefolder);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TFRA8/

You need to check to see if you're having any errors during processing (Firebug or Chrome Console can help). As it stands, your code is not well-formed, as the `$(document).ready()` is never closed in the code you included in the question.

Comment: thanks Jared. the fiddle works unfortunately on my page it still refreshes. there is another form on the page and my input box is inside it. I think I need to take it out of the form then it should work.

Comment: I'd drop the `onkeypress` event method for the `onsubmit`, since that is triggered by an `enter` keypress as well as a `submit` input element click, and AFAICT, you're not doing anything but that. I'd also not use inline event handlers, ie, do not use `onsubmit="return saveFolder()"`, instead use `$('form').submit(handler...)`. Without seeing the actual code and markup live, I'm not sure what to say, except there's an uncaught error or whatnot that "cancels" the code execution and allows the form to continue submitting.

Answer (score 1):

Simply [stop the propagation of the event](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) at the time of the form submission

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#whatever-form-you-are-pulling-your-values-from").submit(function(event) {
    var foldername = $('#foldername').val();
    var foldercolor = $('#foldercolor').val();

    event.stopPropagation();

    //  ajax request to add the folder
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: '../addfolder.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + koo,       
      beforeSend: function() { fe('#r'+koo).slideToggle("slow"); }, 
      success: function() {  }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since by default on a form the enter button submits the form, you need to not only handle this with your own code, but cancel the event after.

Try this code instead:

```
onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) {savefolder(); return false;}"
```

The onkeypress event will that the return value of the javascript and only continue with it's events if it returns true.